# Output text File creation/saving VBA code timing issue

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

**Problem Summary:** Creating a text file for FTP commands is not finishing by the time the command file needs to be called.  It won't trap with a "if file exists".  How to make sure the file is created before continuing with the code?

**Details:** I'm working on an portion of code in my Excel workbook to FTP some files. To do that, I'm creating a FTPcmd.txt file via code containing the FTP commands, closing the file and then shelling the FTP command in the CMD window. It looks like the command file is taking too long to complete the write and, therefore, I'm getting an "Permission Refused" error. The FTP log says "Error opening script file C:\temp\FTPcmd.txt." I am error checking to see if the file exists, but I think the file shows up as existing after the open statement, not the close. I'm not hitting the else statement in the DIR <>"" The IsFileOpen function was found on ["http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=468 VBA Express : Excel - Check If a File Is Already Open"](http://%22http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=468)

I don't believe it's a problem ShellWait problem. I need the file to write *before* I call the Shell.

If I step through it manually, it works, after I see the file appear in the directory.

I'm also piping the FTP output to a file and reading it back in for success/failure messaging in a similar manner and I'm getting the same problem with that.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
Open temppath & "FTPcmd.txt" For Output As #2    
    Print #2, "user " & FSOUserName
    Print #2, FSOpw
    Print #2, "lcd " & temppath
    Print #2, "cd public_html"
    Print #2, "binary"
    Print #2, "mput " & Chr(34) & "index.htm" & Chr(34)
    Print #2, "cd .."
    Print #2, "cd public_ftp"
    Print #2, "mput " & Chr(34) & myfilename & Chr(34)
    Print #2, "bye"
Close #2
Start = Timer
FTPlooper:
If Timer - Start > 30 Then saveme = 1: Text = Text & " FTP Failure": GoTo failpoint
If Dir(temppath & "FTPcmd.txt") <> "" And IsFileOpen(temppath & "FTPcmd.txt") = False Then
    Shell "cmd /c ftp -n -i -g -s:" & temppath & "FtpCmd.txt " & FSOHostURL & ">" & temppath & "ftpout.txt 2>&1"
Else
    GoTo FTPlooper
End If
```

Here's the function I'm using to see if the file is open.

Code:

```
Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)'http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=468
    Dim iFilenum As Long
    Dim iErr As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    iFilenum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
    Close iFilenum
    iErr = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case iErr
    Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True
    Case Else: Error iErr
    End Select

End Function
```

Output of FTPout.txt:

> Error opening script file C:\Users\Theresa\Downloads\FTPcmd.txt.
>
> Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
>   (sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.
>
> FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer]
>   [-r:recvbuffer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]
>
> -v              Suppresses display of remote server responses.   -n 
>   Suppresses auto-login upon initial connection.   -i              Turns
>   off interactive prompting during multiple file
>                     transfers.   -d              Enables debugging.   -g              Disables filename globbing (see GLOB command).   -s:filename
>   Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
>                     commands will automatically run after FTP starts.   -a              Use any local interface when binding data connection.   -A              login as anonymous.   -x:send sockbuf Overrides the default SO_SNDBUF size of 8192.   -r:recv sockbuf Overrides the
>   default SO_RCVBUF size of 8192.   -b:async count  Overrides the
>   default async count of 3   -w:windowsize   Overrides the default
>   transfer buffer size of 65535.   host            Specifies the host
>   name or IP address of the remote
>                     host to connect to.
>
> Notes:
>     - mget and mput commands take y/n/q for yes/no/quit.
>     - Use Control-C to abort commands.

Comment: This strikes me as a "wrong tool for the job" problem. Any particular reason this *needs* to be done with VBA?

Comment: @Mat - I'm doing it in VBA mostly to make it user friendly. If I can do it reliably here, it's less steps for non-computer types.

Comment: @Martin - I'm waiting for the file to write _before_ the shell command but thanks for the info. It could come in handy later.

Comment: At risk of beating a dead horse... couldn't you just put it in a batch file and have the "non-computer types" double-click a shortcut?

Comment: @Martin- The "permission refused" error is generated by the FTP shell when it can't find the site parameters because the command file isn't there to provide it.

Comment: I understood that the "FTP shell" yields "Error opening script file C:\temp\FTPcmd.txt.". Can you show us the exact contents of the `ftpout.txt`?

Comment: Also I assume you get the error even without the loop, right? (I assume it's your attempt for a workaround). Can you remove the loop to simply the code? I guess it confuses many readers.

Comment: @Marc - yeah, I have a few work arounds, but now it's just pissing me off. I want to dominate this program!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Output of FTPout.txt added to problem.  Yes, the error loop was my try at trapping for the file not found, which has not worked.

Comment: Where's the "Permission refused"?

Comment: What happens if you just print the file like: `Shell "cmd /c type " & temppath & "FtpCmd.txt >" & temppath & "ftpout.txt 2>&1"`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - The "Permission Refused" comes as a message box when the shell FTP command is run. That's when ftpout.txt says that the FtpCmd.txt can't be found. The shell FTP commands won't except the instructions directly, it needs a command file. The problem isn't in the shell FTP command itself.  The problem is that the FtpCmd.txt file isn't done writing by the time the shell is called.  How do I stop the code from executing until the file is completely written and ready to go, or how do I detect when it is fully written?

Comment: The file is finished writing with the `Close` command. You do not need any explicit code to wait for a file to finish writing. The problem must be elsewhere. Remove the loop to simplify the code. The loop does not help. Then debug the code line by line until the error message shows and post a screenshot of the code editor with execution point as well as the message box.